# Is it possible to have a variable range and columns using csvRead in Scilab 5.5.2

Tags: scilab

I am a fairly novice, self-taught programmer using Scilab. I have .csv files that I want to read. They are mixed text and numerical values, and have a variable numbers of columns and rows. The part of the file I am interested in has a fixed amount of columns but not rows. I can skip the first part using the header argument but also have cells at the bottom that I do not need. An example of what it could look like:

```
DATA,1,0,3,3960.4,3236,3373,-132
DATA,1,0,4,4544.5,3530,3588,-76
RANDOM TEXT,0
INFO,1,0,#+BHO0 _:WRF&-11,S%00-0-03-1       
INFO,2,1,#*BHO0 _8WRF&-11,NAS%00-0-15-1
```

I am only interested in the lines that start with DATA. If I try to run csvRead without removing the lines below I get this error:

```
Warning: Inconsistency found in the columns. At line 4993, found 2 columns 
while the previous had 8.
```

I currently have a program that will read the file and manipulate it as required but I have to go into each file and delete the bottom rows. Is there a way to get around this?

My current program looks something like this:

```
D = uigetfile([".csv"],"path", "Choose a file name", %t);
filename = fullfile(D);
sub = ["DATA" "0"];

//Import data
data = csvRead(filename, ',', [], 'string', sub, [], [], 34);
edit(filename)
//determine # of rows
data_size = size(data);
limit = data_size(1);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to specify that `csvRead` should ignore lines with less columns, or to use a default set or anything (what would be nice). 
A workaround could be in your case, to only parse lines starting with `DATA`. This can be accomplished with [Regular Expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html).

The `regexpcomments` argument of [`csvRead`](https://help.scilab.org/doc/5.5.2/en_US/csvRead.html) gives the opportunity to ignore lines in the csv file matching a certain regular expression. Next to this, it is also possible to write a regular expression that matches all strings that do **not** match a certain pattern:

```
/^(?:(?!PATTERN).)*$/;    # Matches strings not containing PATTERN
```

Applying this regex in your case, would lead that all lines **not** containing PATTERN, are to be assumed as comments and thus will be ignored.

In code that means something like the following.

```
filename = fullfile('data.csv');
sub = ["DATA" "0"];

//Import data
number_of_header_lines = 1
read_only_lines_starting_with = 'DATA'
regexp_magic = '/^(?:(?!' + read_only_lines_starting_with + ').)*$/'

data = csvRead(filename, ',', [], 'string', sub, regexp_magic, [], number_of_header_lines);

disp(data)
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly!